# Multiple NextJs application in single nginx configuration

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js

I have a root directory `/var/www/html/`
In above root directory I have multiple projects example `project1` `project2`

I want to host two NextJs application in single file of nginx configuration.

Below is my nginx config file

```
location / {
            root /var/www/html/project1/;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
            add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store";
    }
    location /_next/static/ {
            alias /var/www/html/project1/.next/static/;
            expires 365d;
            access_log off;
    }
    location /blog/ {
            rewrite /blog/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_cache my_cache;
            root /var/www/html/project2/;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3003/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
            add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store";
    }
    location /blog/_next/static/ {
            alias /var/www/html/project2/.next/static/;
            expires 365d;
            access_log off;
    }
```

When I run the project2 i.e `mydomain.com/blog` on production server, chunk is serving from root not from blog eg:

```
mydomain.com/_next/static/chunks/4574.41d99ce27dfde7f6.js
```

expected result - `mydomain.com/blog/_next/static/chunks/4574.41d99ce27dfde7f6.js`

**Edit-**
Also we can use next.config.js for the same. My code is

```
const blogAppRewrites = [
  {
    source: "/",
    destination: "/blog",
  },
];

module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return blogAppRewrites;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the way you are setting up the alias and the proxy_pass for the second application. In /blog/_next/static/ location, you are using the alias directiv. But for the /blog/ location you are using the root directive. I think probably this is causing the server to look for files in the wrong location, leading to incorrect URLs. You could use try_files directive in the /blog/ location to allow Nginx to serve static files from the expected location and routes the remaining requests to the appropriate proxy. Try something like this,

```
location /blog/ {
    rewrite /blog/(.*) /$1 break;
    root /var/www/html/project2/;
    try_files $uri @blog;  
}

location @blog {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3003/;
    # Other proxy settings...
}
```

Comment: I have replaced `project2` setting by above configuration still showing the same. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
location / {
    root /var/www/html/project1/;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store";
}

location /_next/static/ {
    alias /var/www/html/project1/.next/static/;
    expires 365d;
    access_log off;
}

location /blog/ {
    rewrite ^/blog/(.*) /$1 break; # Modified rewrite rule
    proxy_cache my_cache;
    root /var/www/html/project2/;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3003/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store";
}

location /blog/_next/static/ {
    alias /var/www/html/project2/.next/static/;
    expires 365d;
    access_log off;
}
```

The key change here is in the location /blog/ block. The rewrite rule has been modified to remove the /blog/ prefix from the URI before passing it to the upstream server. This ensures that the URLs are correctly handled by the second Next.js application, and the chunks will be served from the expected /blog/_next/static/ directory.

After making this change, your NGINX configuration should serve the chunks from the correct subdirectories for both Next.js applications.

Comment: above code is also not working.

Comment: Did you tried restarting nginx server?

Comment: Yes tried reload and restart both.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the base path to your second project - so it knows it gets served from a subdirectory and requests the files from it?

So I think you should try to add

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/blog',
}
```

inside the `next.config.js` of your project2.

Like described here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/basePath